Magento 2 custom product grid, I posted the data with two custom columns, but the customer_special_price is missing from the post data when saving
<?php

namespace Bliss\PricePerCustomer\Block\Adminhtml\Tab;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Backend\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Bliss\PricePerCustomer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerPriceProdcut\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Manager;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;

class Productgrid extends Extended
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $productFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Bliss\PricePerCustomer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerPriceProdcut\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $productCollFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context    $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data               $backendHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory      $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry                $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager          $moduleManager
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param Visibility|null                            $visibility
     * @param array                                      $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Data $backendHelper,
        ProductFactory $productFactory,
        CollectionFactory $productCollFactory,
        Registry $coreRegistry,
        Manager $moduleManager,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Visibility $visibility = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->productCollFactory = $productCollFactory;
        $this->coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->visibility = $visibility ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Visibility::class);
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * [_construct description]
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('bliss_grid_products');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id')) {
            $this->setDefaultFilter(['in_products' => 0]);
        } else {
            $this->setDefaultFilter(['in_products' => 1]);
        }
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('bliss_pricepercustomer/*/customerPrice', ['_current' => true]);
    }

    /**
     * [get store id]
     *
     * @return Store
     */
    protected function _getStore()
    {
        $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $collection = $this->productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
            'sku'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'name'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'attribute_set_id'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'type_id'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'special_price'
        )->setStore(
            $store
        );

        // Joining additional attributes like price, status, visibility as per your original logic
        if ($this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Magento_CatalogInventory')) {
            $collection->joinField(
                'qty',
                'cataloginventory_stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left'
            );
        }

        if ($store->getId()) {
            $collection->setStoreId($store->getId());
            $collection->addStoreFilter($store);
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'name',
                'catalog_product/name',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'status',
                'catalog_product/status',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'visibility',
                'catalog_product/visibility',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute('price', 'catalog_product/price', 'entity_id', null, 'left', $store->getId());
        } else {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
            $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
            $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        }
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        if ($column->getId() == 'in_products') {
            $productIds = $this->_getSelectedProducts();
            if (empty($productIds)) {
                $productIds = 0;
            }
            if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $productIds]);
            } else {
                if ($productIds) {
                    $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => $productIds]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Extended
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'in_products',
            [
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'html_name' => 'products_id',
                'required' => true,
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                'align' => 'center',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'width' => '50px',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'type' => 'number',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            [
                'header' => __('Name'),
                'index' => 'name',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-type',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-type',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'type_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Type'),
                'index' => 'type_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-type',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-type',
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'sku',
            [
                'header' => __('SKU'),
                'index' => 'sku',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-sku',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-sku',
            ]
        );
        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'type' => 'price',
                'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                'index' => 'price',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-price',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-price',
            ]
        );

        // Add new columns for the additional fields
        $this->addColumn(
            'special_price',
            [
                'header' => __('Special Price'),
                'type' => 'price',
                'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                'index' => 'special_price',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-special-price',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-special-price',
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'customer_price',
            [
                'header' => __('Customer Price'),
                'type' => 'input',
                'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                'index' => 'customer_price',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-customer-price',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-customer-price',
                
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'customer_special_price',
            [
                'header' => __('Customer Special Price'),
                'type' => 'input',
                'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                'index' => 'customer_special_price',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-customer-special-price',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-customer-special-price',
            ]
        );
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getSelectedProducts()
    {
        $products = array_keys($this->getSelectedProducts());
        return $products;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSelectedProducts()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $model = $this->productCollFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $id);
        $grids = [];
        foreach ($model as $key => $value) {
            $grids[] = $value->getProductId();
        }
        $prodId = [];
        foreach ($grids as $obj) {
            $prodId[$obj] = ['position' => "0"];
        }
        return $prodId;
    }

    public function getCustomerPrice()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $collection = $this->productCollFactory->create();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $id);
        $customerPrices = [];
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $customerPrice = $item->getCustomerPrice();
        }
        return $customerPrices;
    }


    public function getCustomerSpecialPrice()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $collection = $this->productCollFactory->create();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $id);
        $customerPrices = [];
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $customerPrice = $item->getCustomerSpecialPrice();
        }
        return $customerPrices;
    }
}


Modify the Grid Preparation:
$this->addColumn(
            'customer_special_price',
            [
                'header' => __('Customer Special Price'),
                'type' => 'price', // Change to 'price' type
                'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                'index' => 'customer_special_price',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-customer-special-price',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-customer-special-price',
                'renderer' => '\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Input'
                // Explicitly set input renderer
            ]
        );

